# Are tuples comparable in SML?

Tags: tuples, sml

Suppose we needed to compare values inside tuples (to give context, let's say a tuple of 3 values represents a data dd/mm/yy) & we want to check which if date1< date2.

Is it possible to compare tuples?

```
fun is_older(date1:int*int*int, date2:int*int*int) =
 (#3 date1, #2 date1, #1 date1) < (#3 date2, #2 date2, #1 date2);
```

This answer was generated by chatGPT & gave an error. I correctly implemented a similar function using if statements, but was wondering if tuples are actually comparable.

Comment: ChatGPT generates responses that look plausible, but it literally does not know anything. You should always verify its claims with a reliable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I suggest pattern matching. It's cleaner.

```
fun is_older((a, b, c), (x, y, z)) =
 (c, b, a) < (z, y, x);
```

Second, no. The type of `op<` is `int * int → bool`.